# Lemma for proof of Jordan-Hölder Theorem

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

**Lemma**

Let $G$ be a group, $K \triangleleft G$ a normal subgroup and $H_j \triangleleft H_i$ two subgroups of $G$ with $H_j$ a normal subgroup of $H_i$.

Then there is an isomorphism

$$(H_i K)/(H_j K) \cong (H_i/H_j)/((H_i \cap K)/(H_j \cap K))$$

(and all its parts are well-defined).

I think, I proved this Lemma (as a step in proving the Jordan-Hölder-Theorem), but the argument was, albeit elementary, quite lengthy. So I would be more comfortable to find a reference for this result (either in a textbook or in a research article).

Please excuse, if this is a bit too simple for MathOverflow, but I was hoping that the chances to find a specialist with a good overview over known results are higher here, than at math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

There is an elegant and simple way: First use the "cancellation" theorem to get $\frac{H_i K}{H_j K} \cong \frac{H_i K / K}{H_j K / K}$. Then use another one of the isomorphism theorem to get $\frac{H_i K}{K} \cong \frac{H_i}{H_i \cap K}$ and similarly for $H_j$.

Both theorems provide you with explicit isomorphisms that you can use. In fact you have to use them to make good on the promise that "all parts are well-defined". Set theoretically $(H_i \cap K)/(H_j \cap K)$ is not a subgroup of $H_i/H_j$ if we define them via the usual coset construction, but there *is* a natural embedding which I assume you meant. And that embedding must be used in combination with the two isomorphisms above.

Comment: Thank you for encouraging me to believe in my Lemma - if you would like to take a look at my proof, I put it at http://www.aviduratas.de/prolisp/jh-lemma.pdf